# How can I customize a KotlinCompile task with a Gradle Kotlin buildSrc plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to simplify some of my Gradle builds. A typical `build.gradle.kts` looks like

```kotlin
plugins {
    base
    idea
    java
    id("biz.aQute.bnd.builder")
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.annotation:7.0.0")
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:7.0.0")
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.core:7.0.0")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}

tasks.compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }
}

tasks.compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }
}

version = "0.0.0"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.jar {
    archiveBaseName.set("project.name.api")
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I'm trying to reduce repetition, specifically with the `tasks.compileKotlin` and `tasks.compileTestKotlin` blocks.

I've read that I should use the `buildSrc` folder for defining simplifications like this. The structure of the folder is

```
buildSrc/
  src/
    main/
      kotlin/
        Example.kt
  build.gradle.kts
```

Example.kt

```kotlin
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.dependencies
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.kotlin
//import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

fun KotlinBuildScript.configureModule() {
    tasks.named<KotlinCompile>("compileKotlin") {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
        }
    }
}
```

buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But this setup just results in an `Unresolved reference: kotlin` error during the build.

I can't figure out what I need to change where in order to successfully reference the KotlinCompile class. I tried specifying the kotlin plugin, idea plugin, and tried adding dependencies to kotlin in the `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, but I haven't been able to find any examples on github or google on how to set this up.

I'd like to do the same for most of the build script as well, not just the KotlinCompile task, so any guidance on what or how I should search for these other task types would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're creating an extension function on `KotlinBuildScript` which may or may not be the issue. Regardless, there's no need for extension functions since you can just use the DSL directly.

Gradle calls the shared build logic *convention plugins*: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#compiling_convention_plugins

So your `Example.kt` would become `kotlin-conventions.gradle.kts`:

```
// kotlin-conventions.gradle.kts

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside your main Gradle build file, apply the convention plugin:

```
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    `kotlin-conventions`
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Part of my problem was that I was using version 1.4.31 of the `kotlin-gradle-plugin`, which was contributing to the errors I was having. I'll post an answer for my final result, based on this.

Answer (score 1):

**Credit goes to Francisco Mateo's answer, this exists only for a complete final product**

One additional problem I was having, was that I was trying to use `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.31` in by `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` file. There's some weird bug there, but downgrading slightly to `1.4.30` resolved the contributing issue.

My final configuration looks like

`buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("biz.aQute.bnd.builder:biz.aQute.bnd.builder.gradle.plugin:5.3.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.4.20")
}
```

Each of the external plugins required in the subsequent plugin file need to be specified as dependencies in the `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` file, as specified in the [Applying an external plugin in precompiled script plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html#applying_an_external_plugin_in_precompiled_script_plugin) section from the link in Francisco's answer.

The plugin file also needs the `.gradle.kts` extension (if using Kotlin), so my `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/hummingbird-conventions.gradle.kts` file looks like

```kotlin
plugins {
    base
    idea
    java
    id("biz.aQute.bnd.builder")
    id("org.jetbrains.dokka")
    kotlin("jvm")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.annotation:7.0.0")
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.cmpn:7.0.0")
    implementation("org.osgi:osgi.core:7.0.0")
    testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.1.0")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks {
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
        }
    }
    compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
            useIR = true
        }
    }
    named<Test>("test") {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
}
```

And I could apply this in the subproject's `build.gradle.kts` file like

```kotlin
plugins {
    `hummingbird-conventions`
}
```

where the plugin id is the file name in the `buildSrc` src folder.

Comment: when we have `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30")` in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, should we also add `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"` to project level gradle.build.kts?